# Creating a PHP 'controller' file to build all pages on site

Tags: php, function, url, controller

I was working on another project using the CodeIgniter framework, which had a main controller file that built all of the pages on the site.

Entering a url such as 'domain.com/about' would run 'function about(){' in the controller file, which loaded in the various components of that page.

Most of the magic of this was handled by either CodeIgniter, or the other project members, so I am unsure exactly how that happens.

I am looking to achieve the same thing, without the use of any frameworks, and am at a complete loss of how to accomplish it. I know that it would be possible for me to have a url somewhere along the lines of 'domain.com?load=about', and use this to run that function, but I want the URL to be clean, and easy for visitors to type in.

So, my question is.. How can I set up my website so that it always points to a single file, 'controller.php', and then run's a function which matches what is input in the URL, AND have that URL not direct me away from the controller page? (That is to say, if I type in 'domain.com/about' I don't want to get taken to an about.php page!)

I apologize in advance if this question is hard to understand, or if I am taking the wrong approach to anything. Also for the lack of examples and descriptions.. I just really don't know enough to be any more specific. If there is anything you need to see, or know, just ask and I will do my best to clarify!

Thanks!

Comment: Use frameworks. Don't reinvent the wheel. MVC frameworks have so much more baked into them than controllers. Security, XSS prevention, best practices and conventions for CPU and RAM optimization (some, not all), cache, etc. That being said, CI is great for quick site builds, but if you want to learn check out Zend MVC or Yii.

Comment: If you want to learn, download the CI source files and see how they do it.

Comment: You need to read up about mod_rewrite. That's generally how frameworks will dynamically redirect all traffic to the controller script(s).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into mod_rewrite. I am avoiding using frameworks at this point since my projects are so small in scale. Additionally, learning how to do it myself will help me understand the frameworks better once I do begin to delve into it.

Comment: @BlakeMann: Added quite an extensive description of all the pre-controller flow of most PHP frameworks for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't had many good answers on this. Let's add a lot more detail.

## How CodeIgniter works

### URL Routing

CodeIgniter's first step is actually done outside of CodeIgniter itself. You will find this step in your HTTP daemon. If it is Apache, you will see a rewrite rule similar to this:

```
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

And if you are running nginx, you will see:

```
  rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
```

This is one of the core directives of every framework, and will cause it to process and parse every single request (with, based on `RewriteCond`/`try_files` directives, may include files found or not). The query string provided by the user will be available in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Keep this in mind, we will come back to this more than once.

### Enter the framework

Your framework, if you plan on building one, should feature something called a **Router**. This is a neat little class (or collection of classes) that will handle the dynamic creation of **routes**. Routes are directional mappings between an URI (possibly containing wildcards) and a controller's function (or functions).

This is often overlooked by people writing their own frameworks for the first time, and can make the difference between something that works, and something that is such a royal pain to use (the difference in PHP is slim. This really becomes apparent on other technologies).

So. A router. Takes a list of routes, converts them to classes and functions. We'll want to cache our controllers and provide the dynamic allocation of them, so we will bring a new concept to the table: **Inversion of Control**. This will be familiar to you if you have worked with more recent frameworks (Kohona, Laravel etc). Effectively, it allows you to bind class names to go-to strings and control the instantiation of such classes through a mediator (thereby following the Hollywood principle - you request the controller, you do not instantiate it).

A classical IoC wrapper looks like this:

```
 class IoC {
      private static $cache = array();
      private static $singletons = array();
      public static function register($name,$className,$isSingleton=false) {
          if (!isset(self::$cache[$name])) {
              self::$cache[$name] = array("class" => $className, "singleton" => !!$isSingleton);
          }
      }
      public static function instance($name) {
          if (!isset(self::$cache[$name])) throw new Exception("Class not found in IoC container");
          $cN = self::$cache[$name]['class'];
          if (!empty(self::$cache[$name]['singleton'])) {
               if (!isset(self::$singletons[$cN])) {
                     self::$singletons[$cN] = new $cN();
               }
               return self::$singletons[$cN];
          }
          else {
               return new $cN();
          }
      }
 }
```

This has multiple benefits:

- You may very well one day decide to change your controller to `Controller2` from `Controller1`. By using the `IoC` wrapper to resolve it, you're saving yourself some pain -  not having to go across your entire code
- Handles `Singletons` natively without making them hard to unit-test

So. Strong with our knowledge, we can now instantiate a class based on an arbitrary keyword of our choosing using `IoC::instance("ourkeyword");`. We're going to be using this quite a bit in a tiny bit. First off, one warning: **this IoC wrapper assumes that you will use spl_autoload to lazy-load your classes**.

The router itself will be something along the lines of:

```
 class Router {
      public $routes = array();
      public function register($route, $controller, $method, $request_type=7) {
           $this->routes[] = array("route" => $route, "call" => array($controller, $method), "request_type" => 7);
      }
      public function route($str) {
           foreach ($this->routes as $v) {
               // Do your request_type match here. Exercise left for the reader!
               if (preg_match($str, $v['route'], $matches)) {
                      try {
                         $controller = IoC::instance($v['call'][0]);
                         if (!method_exists($controller, $v['call'][1])) throw new Exception("Method not found: ".$v['call'][1]);
                         array_shift($matches);
                         call_user_func_array(array($controller,$v['call'][1]), $matches);
                      } catch (Exception $e) {
                      }
               }
           }
      }
 }
```

That's your router! You may be wondering why `IoC` is purely a static class, and `Router` is instantiated. The reason is simple: you may want your modules to have their own sub-router rather than having to always deal with one router. I tend to do that a lot, which allows me to completely compartmentalize my PAC structures and build a logical routing hierarchy.

That's all the routing! From the front, your framework code now looks like:

```
  IoC::register("controller1","My\\Controller");
  $router = new Router();
  $router->register(...);
  $router->route($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Nice, neat and abstracting away all the problems! From this, you can build your framework to follow a MVC architecture or any of its variants. This works stupidly well with PAC.

Answer (score 2):

OK seems you are working with PHP. Means that, most probably you'll be using Apache web server. In the .htaccess, you can have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

All your requests shall be redirected to index.php, your main controller.

Now inside index.php, you have

```
$URI_parsed = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$URI_parts  = explode('/', $URI_parsed['path']);
```

You can now use $URI_parts to decide what to do. Example

```
if ($URI_parts[0] == 'about')
    about();
```

If you are at ease with [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), then maybe

```
$func = $URI_parts[0];
$func();
```

In any case you have to deal with $URI_parts[x] (where x > 0), e.g. the URL is

```
www.mydomain.com/products/my_product_item
```

In this case $URI_parts[0] = products and $URI_parts[1] = my_product_item

This is a very basic start. Hope it helps you to build further.

I'll recommend you to use a framework. For example Fat-Free-Framework (F3). You have others. So up to you to decide.

Answer (score -1):

To do this, you will need to redirect all traffic to your main `controller` page.  You can do this using Apache's `mod_rewrite` module or IIS's `web.config` files (for lower versions of IIS, you will need to look into `mod_rewrite` modules for it).  Using these, you can turn your pretty url into something more recognizeable to your program.  How you do this depends on your implementation.  Taking your explanation, you could do something like this:

```
$action = 'index'; //Used for first visiting the site
if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}
if(function_exists($action)) {
    $action();
}
else {
    //Display 404 error
}
```

Now, this is a very simple example, but will do what you have described in your post.

If you were to do something more complex, you could separate your code into multiple files and use OOP (classes).  Doing this will allow your to have public/private functions and allow you to have more complex urls such as www.example.com/items/12.  You will, of course, still want to make sure that the method is available.  To do this, you can use PHP's [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) function.

Comment: I'd -1 this multiple times if I could. This is in no way a "good" or even "best" practice due to global namespace pollution, impossibility to dynamically allocate modules, complete loss of all OOP benefits, does not address the OP's question, and even better: you actually **suggested Reflection for something where Reflection is *NOT* an answer**. If you're curious, check how much overhead `ReflectionClass` has.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld I apologize.  I did not mean that the OP should lose all OOP benefits.  When I suggested using `ReflectionClass`, I was referring more to using named parameters in his query string (using `ReflectionMethod`), which really wouldn't apply here if he were to use `mod_rewrite`.  I have edited my answer, and hope that I haven't caused any confusion.